# SQL Server Query - Explanation Below

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

Stuck on how to achieve the following, we believe with either an IF/ELSE or CASE/WHEN statement:

We have one Item, with the following properties.

```
Item = ABC
Buy Quantity = 6
Tolerance Quantity = 4
```

We are trying to figure out how to calculate the Charged Quantity, the following is how it would work

```
Ordered Quantity    Charged Quantity
1                   1
1.5                 1.5
3.83                3.83
4                   6
5.54                6
6                   6
7                   7
8.32                8.32
9                   9
10                  12
11.9                12
12                  12
```

The buy quantity is 6 and the tolerance quantity is 4. This means that when the ordered quantity becomes in range of 4-6, it should take the buy quantity.

If it is not in this range, then it simply takes the Ordered Quantity.

The tricky part is doing this when the Ordered Quantity falls into each "range" of the Buy Quantity (Multiples of 6 in this example):

```
6(4-6)
12(10-12)
18(16-18)
24(22-24)
and so on...
```

Each item could have different Buy/Tolerance quantities.

Interested to see your solutions/advice.

Below is the create table statement with values:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackQuestion](
    [OrderedQty] [numeric](19, 6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(1.000000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(1.500000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(3.830000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(4.000000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(5.540000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(6.000000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(7.000000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(8.320000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(9.000000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(10.000000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(11.900000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([OrderedQty]) VALUES (CAST(12.000000 AS Numeric(19, 6)))
```

Working query as per suggestions:

```
declare @BuyQuantity as numeric(19,6)
declare @ToleranceQuantity as numeric(19,6)

set @BuyQuantity = 6
set @ToleranceQuantity = 4

SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN OrderedQty >= @ToleranceQuantity AND OrderedQty <= @BuyQuantity THEN @BuyQuantity 
ELSE OrderedQty 
END AS ChargedQuantity
FROM StackQuestion
```

As you can see in the working query, rows 10, 11 & 12 should return 10, 11.9 and 12.
How do we make them 12, 12 and 12?

Comment: How your question is related to sql you've tagged? I see here only calculation of some function(quantity), and nothing about sql.

Comment: Sorry but unable to understand "when the Ordered Quantity falls into each "range"?

Comment: Andy, I have edited the post, was thinking IF/ELSE or CASE/WHEN to achieve the desired result.
Dev D, I have added an additional comment to the "range" sentence. It is related to the desired results set I included above.

Comment: Well, can you provide the create stmts of your tables?

Comment: I will do and edit the post.

Comment: Post edited with table/values creation and working query.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate ChargedQuantity like this:

```
CASE
WHEN OrderedQuantity >= ToleranceQuantity AND OrderedQuantity <= BuyQuantity THEN BuyQuantity 
ELSE OrderedQuantity 
END AS ChargedQuantity
```

Comment: Thanks Panayotis, but I don't believe this will work when the Ordered Quantity falls into the next "range". I will try when I get a moment, but if the Ordered Quantity is greater than 6, it will not round to the "range", EG: (If Ordered Quantity is 11, it will show 11 instead of 12).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a CASE statement to embed in your SQL results, otherwise its trivial to apply this logic.

Answer above is correct,

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN OQ >= TolQ AND OQ <= BQ THEN BQ 
        ELSE OQ 
    END ChargedQty
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have added the create table/values and working query with what I am trying to achieve.
Curious for you to explain why it is trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.  The table definition and data only has 1 column, so I'm guessing you want to use Row_Number inside the CASE statement?
I consider IF statements pretty trivial, especially for this kind of problem.  The CASE statement people have provided is also pretty trivial, but clearly we're missing the point somewhere!

Comment: Thanks Chris, possibly the Row_Number could be used.
I will ponder on this. I'll try to see if I can simplify the question.